# mysql_query says error in sql syntax but the same query works fine in mysql client

Tags: php, mysql

When I try to send the following query:

```sql
SET @attempts=0; 
SELECT mt1.TimeStamp, mt1.ReadAttempts - @attempts AS delta, 
       @attempts := mt1.ReadAttempts ReadAttempts 
FROM OneWireStats mt1 
WHERE SensorIndex=1 ORDER BY mt1.TimeStamp;
```

to fetch delta values between rows in table OneWireStats I receive following error:

> Query failed with error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'SELECT mt1.TimeStamp, mt1.ReadAttempts - @attempts
>   AS delta, @attempts := mt1.Re' at line 1 Query = SET @attempts=0;
>   SELECT mt1.TimeStamp, mt1.ReadAttempts - @attempts AS delta, @attempts
>   := mt1.ReadAttempts ReadAttempts FROM OneWireStats mt1 WHERE
>   SensorIndex=1 ORDER BY mt1.TimeStamp;, Query no: 0

When I paste the query from the error printout above into mysql client it works fine.

```
mysql>  SET @attempts=0; SELECT mt1.TimeStamp, mt1.ReadAttempts - @attempts AS delta, @attempts := mt1.ReadAttempts ReadAttempts FROM OneWireStats mt1 WHERE SensorIndex=1 ORDER BY mt1.TimeStamp LIMIT 10; Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

+---------------------+-------+--------------+ 
| TimeStamp           | delta | ReadAttempts |
+---------------------+-------+--------------+ 
| 2013-12-23 07:55:01 |  5532 |         5532 | 
| 2013-12-23 08:00:00 |   302 |         5834 | 
| 2013-12-23 08:05:01 |   302 |         6136 | 
| 2013-12-23 08:10:00 |   302 |         6438 | 
| 2013-12-23 08:15:00 |   302 |         6740 | 
| 2013-12-23 08:20:01 |   302 |         7042 | 
| 2013-12-23 08:25:00 |   302 |         7344 | 
| 2013-12-23 08:30:01 |   302 |         7646 | 
| 2013-12-23 08:35:00 |   302 |         7948 | 
| 2013-12-23 08:40:01 |   302 |         8250 |
+---------------------+-------+--------------+ 
10 rows in set (0.07 sec)
```

I use the following php code:

```php
$query = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($queryobj[$counter]));

$sqlresult = mysql_query($query) or die("Query failed with error: ".mysql_error() . 
             " Query = " . $query . ", Query no: " . $counter);
```

I do not use any single or double quotes in my query so I do not yet understand the error printout.

Greatful for hints.

Comment: First, you shouldn't use the `mysql_` functions in PHP. Use `mysqli` or  PDO instead. Second, you probably aren't allowed to have multiple statements in one query (here, the `SET` and the `SELECT` are separate statements).

Comment: Right, `mysql_query()` does not support multiple `;` delimited statements. You need to call it twice, first to set the variable, then to perform your query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run each query separately, may be like

```
mysql_query( "SET @attempts=0" );
mysql_query( "SELECT mt1.TimeStamp, mt1.ReadAttempts - @attempts AS delta, @attempts := mt1.ReadAttempts ReadAttempts FROM OneWireStats mt1 WHERE SensorIndex=1 ORDER BY mt1.TimeStamp" );
```

OR use [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php)'s [multi_query()](https://www.php.net/mysqli.multi-query), like:

```
$query  = "SET @attempts=0;";
$query .= "SELECT mt1.TimeStamp, mt1.ReadAttempts - @attempts AS delta, @attempts := mt1.ReadAttempts ReadAttempts FROM OneWireStats mt1 WHERE SensorIndex=1 ORDER BY mt1.TimeStamp";
mysqli_multi_query($connection, $query);
mysqli_next_result($connection);
if ($result = mysqli_store_result($connection)) {
  //while loop here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, multiple statements was the problem. After taking care of the statements the script works perfect. :-)

Comment: @user3135539 if it worked then you could mark it as Accepted Answer..!